# Интерполяция на сетку Вороного

Tags: c++, интерполяция, вороной

Подскажите библиотеку на C++ в которой реализован метод интерполяции с регулярной сетки на сетку Вороного. Как я понял нужно искать все пересечения и пропорционально объему ячеек искать среднее значение для ячейки Вороного?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]